# How to run a .exe file through the command prompt in a Java program?

Tags: java, command-line

I've read other questions about running .exe files through command prompt but the answers given did not work for me--I tried several. I am generating input files for this .exe and I need to run them and get the output.

The command is this: C:\exeDir\myExe.exe -b C:\inDir\in.txt C:\outDir\out.txt

I have tried:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\exeDir\\myExe.exe",
"-b C:\\inDir\\in.txt",
"C:\\outDir\\out.txt").start();
```

And

```
String[] cmd = { "C:\\exeDir\\myExe.exe",
 "-b C:\\inDir\\in.txt",
 "C:\\outDir\\out.txt" };
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
     p.waitFor();
```

As well as a few other variations. None have worked. What is the proper way for me to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: So all you want to do is run programm xy from java?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track,

```
try {
  Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
      "C:\\exeDir\\myExe.exe",
      "-b", "C:\\inDir\\in.txt",
      "C:\\outDir\\out.txt").start();
  // to get the result...
  InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  process.waitFor();
  // Process finished.
} catch (Exception e) {
  // print any errors.
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The part of the command: "C:\\outDir\\out.txt" is to create a new file with the output, so it should not exist. When I run this I get the following: The file C:\\outDir\\out.txt could not be found, please try again... How can I avoid this?

Comment: That error must be coming from `myExe.exe`, this code doesn't do anything with those arguments.

Comment: "-b C:\\inDir\\in.txt" should be two separate parameters, so that. "-b" is sent as a separate parameter from "C:\\inDir\\in.txt". Each String in the parameter list is considered a individual parameter passed to the process, this is one of the reasons ProcessBuilder is so good, it deals with parameters that contain spaces better